# Can you turn off custom errors programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

We have a web application that has custom errors turned on so that users see a friendly error. Is there a way to disable custom errors on a per request basis? Say, if we make a request from a specific IP address then custom errors are disabled?

I know you can set it to "RemoteOnly" and custom errors will be off when making requests from localhost, but that requires someone to remote into the machine running the application and make the request from there. It would be nice if we could just write some logic to disable custom errors under certain conditions.

Comment: Have you considered using ELMAH for your yellow screens of death?  Pretty easy to use and very useful.  You can log the original exceptions and have them emailed to you as well.  See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ (available as a nuget package).

Comment: [This](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Ted-Nyberg/Dates/112276/2/Programmatically-configure-customErrors-redirects/) can give you something to start with.

Comment: We do actually use ELMAH. Great tool! It's still just sometimes easier to get the yellow screen without logging into the logged errors and finding it. I was just curious if there was a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one [solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/07/29/troubleshoot-asp-net-errors-remotely-while-appearing-local.aspx) which might work for you.

Comment: Seems URL rewrite module isn't included in Windows Server 2008. I'm gonna have trouble getting management to approve both the installation of the module and the server variable. Probably not going to be able to use this but it's still a unique solution. Thanks for the answer.